# Windows Batch script to add entry to Registry

Tags: batch-file, windows-10, registry

I'm attempting to create a batch script that would reproduce an entry in the registry I created manually. The script is going to be part of the installation process for a small WEB application I'm working on.

The needed entry into the registry is in fact the definition of a custom protocol to be invoked from JavaScript to activate an external process (in this case, a PowerShell script).

The manually generate entry is shown in the following snapshot and it works as needed:

[image]

The script I have so far correctly replicates the shown entry except for the last one (the `command` part) is complaining about a syntax error. Here is the piece of script hat attempts to register the last part of the definition and is triggering the error message:

```
set scriptpath=%~dp0
reg query HKCR\fddmyalbs2\shell\open\command
set Query_Result=%errorlevel%

if "%Query_Result%"=="0" (
    echo "HKCR\fddmyalbs2\shell\open\command OK!"
) else (
    echo "HKCR\fddmyalbs2\shell\open\command missing. Registering..."
    reg add HKCR\fddmyalbs2\shell\open\command /t REG_SZ /d "powershell.exe" %scriptpath%FD_Albums_MNGR.ps1 "^%1" /f
)
```

What is syntax error (in the `reg add` command)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The entire thing can be achieved with a single line batch file:

```bash
@%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe Query "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Classes\fdmyalbs\shell\open\command" 1>NUL 2>&1 && (Echo HKCU\SOFTWARE\Classes\fdmyalbs\shell\open\command OK!& %SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe /T 3 /NoBreak 1>NUL) || (Echo HKCU\SOFTWARE\Classes\fdmyalbs\shell\open\command missing. Registering...& %SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe Add "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Classes\fdmyalbs\shell\open\command" /VE /D "%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -File \"%~dp0MyAlbums\FD_Albums_MNGR.ps1\" \"%%~1\"" 1>NUL)
```

Please note, this uses the information in your registry editor image, and not the modified information in your batch file, (which does not match that). Please do not change the registry root key and subkeys, the ones I have provided are correct, *(you should not be using the `HKCR` root key, which is essentially an amalgamated view of both `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes` and `HKCU\SOFTWARE\Classes`)*. If this is really for all users of the computer, you may replace all instances of `HKCU` with `HKLM`, but please note that the script must then be run elevated. Additionally I have improved your PowerShell command, so I'd advise you to leave that alone too.

---

If you wanted it to be a little more readable then you could split the line over several instead:

```bash
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

Set "RegKey=HKCU\SOFTWARE\Classes\fdmyalbs\shell\open\command"

%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe Query "%RegKey%" 1>NUL 2>&1 && (
    Echo %RegKey% OK!
    %SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe /T 3 /NoBreak 1>NUL
) || (
    Echo %RegKey% missing. Registering...
    %SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe Add "%RegKey%" /VE /D "%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -File \"%~dp0MyAlbums\FD_Albums_MNGR.ps1\" \"%%~1\"" 1>NUL
)
```

Comment: Thank you Compo for your response. Some notes: (1) Your suggestion is too complex for me to understand and maintain (for instance, what is the timeout needed for). (2) Though I understand your reluctance about defining the entry at HKCR level, I've seen many examples for the definition of custom protocols that do just that. (3) I wander why you use `%SystemRoot%` while this is always part of the path. (4), and please understand that I'm not in any disagreement with you, I would very much appreciate if you could let me know what is syntactically wrong in the last command of my code. Thanks.

Comment: 1. The `timeout` allows a few seconds for you to read the `Echo` message before the script ends. 2. Those examples are wrong, they are written by people who do not undrestand how the registry works. 3. `%SystemRoot%\System32` should always be part of the `%PATH%` , however that is very dependent upon the end users configuration, and therefore not guaranteed. Also, relying upon it, (along with the `%PATHEXT%` variable to append file extensions), adds an unnecessary search and check overhead. 4. Change your `/d` to `"powershell.exe \"%scriptpath%FD_Albums_MNGR.ps1\" \"%%~1\""` and remove `/f`.

Comment: Hello Compo. Could you take a look at the UPDATE of the question (as you can see, I'm an OLD FASHIONED guy..)? As explained there, your suggested change [point (4) in your last comment] does resolve the syntax error but does not yield a working result. Thanks again for the time you are investing on this question :-).

Comment: Your code has changed, and there are problems with it outside of the original question. I am not here to support those in this answer. Please open your registry editor, navigate to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\fddmyalbs2\shell\open\command`, right click on the `(default)` value and select `modify` so that you can copy and all of the string data. If your data reads as `powershell.exe "D:\MyAlbums\FD_Albums_MNGR.ps1" "%~1"` then the syntax changes I offered are correct. If it is correct, yet fails, when pasted into a Command Prompt, with a valid argument, then your changes or original value are the issue.

Comment: Dear Compo, first, thanks again for your support. Second, the syntax is indeed fixed (no error) **BUT** things do not work as expected. As explained, I have one protocol manually defined that works (`fdmyalbs`) and a second one that does not (`fddmyalbs2`), being the last aimed to test the script that creates it. They are both invoked from the same piece of code (changing the protocol name only) and yet the test one does not work. I also copied the contents of the "working" command part to the test protocol and it does not work either. I'll need to figure out why. Once again, thanks.

Comment: The first thing you should do is to open your command prompt window, type ```For %G In (LM CU) Do @%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe Query "HK%G\SOFTWARE\Classes\fdmyalbs" /S 2>NUL```, press the `[ENTER]` key, and take a look at the output.

Comment: I did what you suggested for both protocols and the only difference is the name of the protocol (comparison done with a program, not only visual). Does these changes require a reboot? (I don't think so, but I'm not 100% sure).

Comment: First of all I'd like to see the output from the exact command I gave you. Can you upload it somewhere, and provide a link? Generally a reboot, or a registry reload, _(which may happen by restarting explorer.exe)_, is required.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no cloud place I can store the image so I added to the original question. My apologies...

Comment: There are hundreds of websites dedicated to text pastes, that could have been used! Did you notice immediately, as per point (2) of your initial comment, that both of your examples are in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes`? It should confirm for you what I said about `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`! For me, that is still not correct, because this custom protocol should be for a specific user, not every user of the machine, (it's My Albs, not Everyone's Albs). Hence the reason I initially offered it as `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes`.

Comment: Very well. I did notice what you are mentioning and will attempt to do what you suggested, meaning, delete the TEST Protocol definition and re-create it under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes. Will update you on the results... Thank you Compo.

Comment: As for your new problem, I'd advise that you submit a new question, complete with all of your new code, the information from your most recent Edit, _which I'll now delete_, (preferably as text in a code box, not an image), and explain to the readers exactly how the end user is to invoke this protocol.

Comment: Will do after the change I mentioned in my previous comment in the case it does not work.

Comment: That change will not fix your issue.

Comment: Compo, as suggested, I created a new entry/question in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77568930/windows-10-script-to-define-custom-protocol-into-registry).